# Python merge 2 vector (shape(1,10,1) arrays into matrix (shape(2,10,1)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have my array:

```
A= np.array(zeros((1,10,1)))
```

and

```
B = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I need to merge A and B into C:

```
C = [[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
     [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]]
```

This:

```
C = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

is not the solution, so it is why I posted this question :D
Thanks for help!

Edit:
Corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, assuming `A = np.zeros(1,9,1)` based on your expected output

```
np.concatenate([A, np.array(B).reshape(A.shape)], axis=0)
```